# quick-Json deserialization casting issues

Tags: java, json, casting, hashmap

I am using [quick-Json](https://code.google.com/p/quick-json/) to serialize a HashMap(String, String[]) in my program, but I am having trouble deserializing the object. I use this code to serialize the map

```
    JsonGeneratorFactory generatorFactory = JsonGeneratorFactory.getInstance();
    JSONGenerator generator = generatorFactory.newJsonGenerator();
    String json = generator.generateJson(allCodes);
```

where all codes is a HashMap(String,String[]). This takes the form

```
[{"key1":["value1","value2"]}]
```

Here is the code I use to deserialize the object

```
    JsonParserFactory parseFactory=JsonParserFactory.getInstance();
    JSONParser parser = parseFactory.newJsonParser();
    output = parser.parseJson(inputString);
```

The output takes the form

```
 {root=[{"key1":["value1","value2"]}]}
```

My goal is to cast the above as a HashMap(String, String[]). The added root parameter makes that difficult though. Is there a way to return back to the desired HashMap?

Comment: Can you call output.get("root").get(0)?

Comment: I can call output.get("root") but that just returns an object, so I cannot go further unless I cast the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
HashMap outputHashMap = (HashMap) (((ArrayList) ((HashMap) parser.parseJson(json)).get("root")).get(0));
```

There is probably a more elegant way, but this is the best I can think of right now.

Comment: I wanted to avoid excessive casting, but that way should work. I decided to (de)serialize the file using base64 instead.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `parser.parseJson(inputString)` use `parser.parse(inputString)`.
That will give you the format you are looking for.

Comment: The only option I get is parser.parseJson(...). There is no parser.parse(...)